# Show Avatar to Github Username after Committing

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, avatar

I have following issue.

I have set up everything on github for using a avatar instead of this random grafic.
If I commit and my colleague views the commits in his github for windows (GFW), it shows him my avatar.
But if I launch my GFW (same version like my colleague) than I get the random grafic.

There is **[a question that has ALMOST the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221280/change-avatar-next-to-github-username-for-commits)**, but he doesn't get any avatar shown. I actually get it shown but not on **MY** GFW.

Is it normal that I can't see it ? If not, how can I get it shown up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change the avatar from the random graphic to the custom version *after* you already used your copy of GFW to download the avatar? If so then it could be that your client is caching the avatar.

You might try looking for the cache--maybe it's in your `Program Data\GitHub` directory or something along those lines. (I'm on a Mac so I can't check or look for it.) If you find something that's obviously a cache you can try clearing it out.

The more heavyweight approach would be to uninstall the client and reinstall it.

**EDIT**

goto <kbd>%LocalAppData%\GitHub\</kbd> and delete `images.cache.db`

restart GFW

Comment: thats it! :D actually i should have tried this by my own :D ... but i guess my mind wasnt opend enough :D

Comment: i added it to my question ^^ ill add it to your answere as well. may you vote my question up :D (bounty can be awarded in 23h)