# Re-authenticating access in git

Tags: git, github, authentication, account

When I set up git, I used one username/email combination.

Then I changed my username and email combination on GitHub.

Now when I try to push to my repositories i get the following error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know the repository exists. So I have a feeling git is trying to communicate with gitHub using my old username and email, which obvi isn't recognized as me now.

How do I erase the stored github account info and re-authenticate in git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part is the username: if you have change GitHub *account*, then you need to make sure your `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (or `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`) is registered in that new account.

The email part is not important (except for the [gravatar displayed with your old commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10221585/6309))

Comment: Sorry I didn't log back in for a while, but that was exactly what I did to fix it. Thank you!